# Server side angularjs

Tags: angularjs, server-side

I'm new with Angular.js. Based on my curent knowledge, I thought that Angular was basically a client-side javascript framework. But a collegue told me that it can be used for server-side purpose: the question is: how to do it? Because when I link a javascript resource as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_myfile.js" />
```

I think that the logic is execute on the client; also: everyone could access to the resource via browser, so that the paradigm of separation between model and view doesn't seem very defined.

Comment: I think Angular can be used to "illusion" a server-side behaviour (just like how technically you can do anything in any language, i.e. PHP can technically do what an Angular script can do with LOTS of pages, sessions and cookies), but for all practical (and 99.9% of cases), Angular can't be used for server side purposes. It works well with Node.js though

Comment: I think this is Angular.. but its Angular2..

Answer (score 0):

I think your collegue was talking about angular-mocks: it can intercept the request meant to be sent to the server and send data back! it just mimicks the behavious of a the backend in case you were working in the front end, and the back end part wasn't ready.

read about it here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock

Comment: This is not an answer.. `ng-mock` used to unit test angular code.. I won't work on server side

Comment: That's what I meant: angular can't work in server side, the only think it can do is mock the server side for unit test purposes

Answer (score 0):

The angular2 runtime has two layers, an application and a rendering layer.
It is possible to do server-rendering with angular2

see more here: [angular2 server rendering](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1q6g9UlmEZDXgrkY88AJZ6MUrUxcnwhBGS0EXbVlYicY/edit?pref=2&pli=1)